# Visual Studio Code Include path

Tags: c, gcc, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors, ide

How do I include commands for gcc in VS Code? The project compiles without any error if i type the following command in the terminal `gcc main.c pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk + -3.0 -export-dynamic`. But I have no idea how to configure this in VS Code.

I tried to include everything in c_cpp_properties.json without any luck.

```
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "linux-gcc-x64",
      "includePath": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/**",
        "/usr/include/gtk-3.0",
        "/usr/include/glib-2.0"
      ],
      "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
      "cStandard": "${default}",
      "cppStandard": "${default}",
      "intelliSenseMode": "linux-gcc-x64",
      "compilerArgs": [
        "-Wall",
        "-Wextra",
        "-Wpedantic",
        "pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0`",
        "-export-dynamic"
      ],
      "defines": [
        ""
      ]
    }
  ],
  "version": 4
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!

`tasks.json`

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
                "`pkg-config",
                "--cflags",
                "--libs",
                "gtk+-3.0`",
                "-export-dynamic"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

[Any tips on how to get rid of the following error message?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgwSp.png)

`#include errors detected. Please update your includePath. Squiggles are disabled for this translation unit (/home/malte/Projects/GtkButton/main/src/main.c).`